# Citing stackexchange postings

Tags: discussion, citation

Have any postings to stackexchange been cited in scholarly publications?

If one does that, should one just name the author, the subject line, the date of posting, and the URL?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2970).

Comment: See [Do I cite mathstackexchange in my paper?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/do-i-cite-mathstackexchange-in-my-paper),
[What is a good standard for publishing a reference to a stackexchange thread?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-a-good-standard-for-publishing-a-reference-to-a-stackexchange-thread) 
and the linked questions.

Comment: Searching Google Scholar for ["math.stackexchange.com"](http://scholar.google.sk/scholar?as_subj=eng&q=%22math.stackexchange.com%22) and
["mathoverflow.net"](http://scholar.google.sk/scholar?as_subj=eng&q=%22mathoverflow.net%22) returns a few results.

Answer (score 21):

Though this has been posted in the comments, it deserves to be more prominently featured: **We have a built-in feature to suggest citation formats**.

1. Click on the *share* button on the bottom of a post in **Main** (it doesn't work on Meta posts). Like so:
   [image]
2. Notice that on the bottom left of the box there is a *cite* link. Click on it and you'd see 
   [image]
   In  the above shown dialog box, you can copy the "Example citation" as it is and paste it into the document you are writing, or if you use the bibliographic systems `BibTeX` or `amsrefs` to produce citation information for your `LaTeX` document, you can copy the associated version of citation information from the code box below. For systems like `EndNote` you will have to either enter the information manually following the example given, or use a converter that imports the `BibTeX` code into the format you desire. Google is your friend for the last.

Comment: On one hand, the share button URL contains a 'q' for questions and an 'a' for answers. On the other hand, the cite button URL contains a 'q' for both questions and answers. Is this a bug? If it is on purpose, why the difference?

Comment: @Qmechanic: I didn't develop the cite code. You should ask this as a new question. Probably on MetaMO.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [discussion on MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/7/cite-mathoverflow/) is perhaps the best place to look. In particular, that thread led to a 'cite' button appearing on each MO post, providing a sample citation, BibTex, and amsrefs.

For example, on [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38639/thinking-and-explaining), which looks like:

[image]

the 'cite' link produces the following for BibTeX:

[image]

and the following for amsrefs:

[image]

Between the sample citations and the bib/ams refs, I can't think of what else you would want. I suspect that this hasn't been added in on MSE because we aren't research-focused.

Comment: It is enabled on MSE, [see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/what-is-a-good-standard-for-publishing-a-reference-to-a-stackexchange-thread/1902#1902). Click `share`, then `cite` (on main, not on meta). In fact, Martin already linked to this post in the comments to the question.

Comment: BTW, I think this should be added to the FAQ. Or RAQ, as the case may be...

Comment: 5PM: I never knew that - Thanks. The things you learn.

Comment: @5PM That is a pretty useful one!

Comment: I thought of editing the broken meta.MO link in your post, but it's not clear if the answer adds any value here at all, since it was posted under mistaken assumption that `cite` is not enabled here. Willie Wong already gave a correct answer. So, maybe just delete this one?